# Firefox extension overlay injects a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

When injecting a JavaScript file on another overlay JavaScript file that puts on a .xul file, I get the message "Filtered chrome URL" instead of loading the JavaScript file.

Code:

```
var myScript = doc.createElement('script');
myScript.type = 'text/javascript';
myScript.setAttribute('src', 'chrome://content/MyScript.js');
myScript.setAttribute('onload', 'doThing();');
doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(myScript);
```

Comment: FYI: JavaScript is one word. Can you show the code that has the issue to go along with your general explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try `var myScript = doc.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul', 'script')` ?